# Using / making text into a procedural shader material in nodes

Tags: texturing, node-editor, bezier-curves, animation-nodes, text-object

I know I can wrap text around a curve but is it possible to use / make text into a procedural shader material using nodes?

I would like to have the text as a procedural shader material to place it exactly where I want it on an object and this would allow me to mix it with another shader using nodes.

PS:  I'm using Blender 2.8

[image: text]

Answer (score 1):

You can import an image with text on it (typically in black an white, acting as a mask in your node setup), but there is no way to write text in a procedural manner with nodes in Blender.

Comment: This is only partially, you could with an INCREDIBLY complex shader, as people have made shaders displaying numbers from a variable input, it's just extremely difficult to do it fully procedurally, and in the end not efficient enough to be worthwhile. I agree an image texture is the best way to go.